# How to mirror video element without mirroring picture-in-picture?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I've got a video chat application that uses a video element to display the user's own webcam. Currently, the application is setup to mirror this video element using `transform: scaleX(-1)`.

The issue I'm running into is when a user selects picture-in-picture mode the browser text "**Playing in picture-in-picture**" is also mirrored.

Is there anyway to flip the text back or another way to mirror the `<video>` element without mirroring this browser text? Or perhaps there's a way to mirror the video without actually mirroring the `<video>` element?

I've looked into using the Picture-In-Picture API's pseudo class but can't seem to get it to work either, and there aren't a lot of examples of it in use.

Comment: might be easier to hide the text with pseudo classes, like color:transparent, since many properties don't work on natives. you can then used content: "pip blah"; on the vid container to avoid the mirroring.

Comment: @dandavis The issue is, the text "Playing in picture-in-picture" isn't selectable so I can't make it transparent.